# Hidden branch in Git

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket

I am new to the use of version control system but I really have no idea about this issue even after a fair bit of researching.

My company has a git repo hosted on BitBucket, it has 2 branches shown online.

[image]

After I `git clone` this repo to my local disk, I tried `git log`, it shows all the commit covered by the green line (the trunk on the left), however those covered by blue branch (*i.e. the commit from 2017-02-20 to 2017-03-23*) simply disappear in the result.

Basically I have done the following things so far:

1. Initial research gave me a hint that those blue commits are probably "hidden", therefore I did `git log -a` but it still doesn't work as expected.
2. I tried `git show #hash`, works well with green commits, but not work with those on the branch.
3. I also cloned this project directly into Eclipse, however in the commit history I still cannot see any commit related to that branch.
4. In my screenshot it looks like there is only one `master` in the repo, but if I click the "master" button, then it ends up with showing green commits too. It looks like there is no way for me to select that branch.

The goal I am currently trying to achieve is to change the HEAD of future commit from `#b4c74fb` rather than from `#ca8e09c`.

Any idea to solve this issue? Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is quite unusual behaviour. I can really only imagine that BitBucket is showing you commits that used to be on a branch but got unreferenced, maybe by accident. In that case there is no way to get at these commits using the Git protocol, and the only possibility would be to use some magic maybe (or maybe not) offered by BitBucket. Maybe you can talk to the BitBucket folks about this?

Comment: _"it has 2 branches shown online."_ - but the menu you have open only shows one branch: master. The one you see in the graph is most likely removed, and is only cached in BitBucket.

Answer (score 5):

It could be that there is some reference which is not in the "heads" namespace. Check what this command prints in the cloned repository:

```
git ls-remote origin
```

If there is a reference *ref* which points to `b4c74fb` you can fetch it with command:

```
git fetch origin _ref_
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use any of below commands to find the commits:

```
git log --oneline --decorate --graph --all
gitk --all
git log --all
```

You will find all the commit histories in your bitbucket repo.